# Форма для поиска доменов

Tags: php

```
echo "<center><form method=\"get\" id=\"searchform\" action=\"?domain=\">
\n"; 
echo "    <input type=\"text\" value=\"$keys\" name=\"domain\" id=\"searchbox\"><right><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Ok\" /></right>
\n"; 
echo "</form></center>  \n";
```

Это форма для поиска доменов. Поиск доменов можно осуществить только в зонах (.com, , .net, .org, .inf, .biz)

Ни как не могу понять как сделать одну функцию.

То есть если сделать поиск по другим зонам, то скрипт должен выдать ошибку и оставить на главной.

**пример domain.com/?domain=love.com** - это правильный урл, если зона подходит, если нет только должен остаться в главной директории и выдать ошибку что не правильный поиск.

Как это сделать? Ни как не могу понять

Answer (score 1):

```
$_GET[domain] - тут у тебя текущий домен
$type = substr($_GET[domain], strlen($_GET[domain])-4, 4); //+ фильтры офк необходимые, но щас я вырезаю остаток
if ($type == '.com')
{успех} else {вывод формы}
```

Comment: А можете сразу в мою форму вписать? Готовый вариант